Reading sequence of values from list in Python
I have list of values and a function that takes n>1 arguments. Values in list are in order (obviously) and I have to iterate through the list to check all possible sequences of values.
The code below works well, but doesn't look really pythonic to me (I particularly don't like  "for i in range" construction). Is there any more elegant and possibly efficient way to achieve the same?
# function that takes 3 arguments
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)


# for this particular list (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)
# are triplets that should be analyzed by foo function
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(L) - 2):
    foo(*L[i : i+3])

Result:
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5


Read this.

You could use the sliding_window recipe described here, but I don't have an issue with the way you are doing this (although you should check out the PEP 8 Style Guide)

Why do you want it efficient? In what way is your actual use case larger?

@nocomment My actual use case is list of vertices in geometry shape (polyline or polygon). There might be big number of vertices and big number of shapes . I am concerned that my code might not be optimal due to the list slicing (most of the values in the really long list will be "sliced" 3 times - in this example only number 3 is "sliced" 3 times).

Note that PEP 8 wants L[i : i+3], not l[i:i + 3].

@nocomment Are you sure? Regarding spaces PyCharm doesn't agree with you. Also please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916806/pep8-e203-error-occurs-in-list-slice. And why L should be uppercase?

Yes I'm sure. It calls ham[lower + offset:upper + offset] wrong and ham[lower+offset : upper+offset] correct, and about l it says "In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the numerals one [...] When tempted to use ‘l’, use ‘L’ instead". What does PyCharm say?

It says: PEP 8: E203 whitespace before ':' But I'm not going to insist that it's error free software. With L of course you're right.

That seems to be a well-known bug, see Google results for "PEP 8: E203".

Some more efficient solutions from me, for 10^5 elements:
  5.1 ± 0.1 ms  me_2
  5.2 ± 0.0 ms  me_1
  7.2 ± 0.1 ms  me_3
 12.8 ± 0.2 ms  Parman_2
 13.0 ± 0.4 ms  Nayem
 27.0 ± 0.4 ms  original

Python: 3.12.2 (main, May 17 2024, 19:27:45) [GCC 14.1.1 20240507]

Code:
def me_1(l):
    it = iter(l)
    a = next(it, None)
    b = next(it, None)
    for c in it:
        foo(a, b, c)
        a = b
        b = c

def me_2(l):
    it = iter(l)
    a = next(it, None)
    b = next(it, None)
    f = foo
    for c in it:
        f(a, b, c)
        a = b
        b = c

def me_3(l):
    b = iter(l)
    next(b, None)
    c = iter(l)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    deque(map(foo, l, b, c), 0)

def original(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 2):
        foo(*l[i:i + 3])

def Parman_1(l):
    for values in windowed(l, 3):
        foo(*values)

def Parman_2(l):
    for values in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):
        foo(*values)

def Nayem(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 2):
        foo(l[i], l[i + 1], l[i + 2])

funcs = [
    original,
   # Parman_1,
    Parman_2,
    Nayem,
    me_1,
    me_2,
    me_3,
]

from itertools import *
from collections import deque
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random

# Correctness
def foo(a, b, c):
    result.append((a, b, c))
for n in range(20):
    l = [object() for _ in range(n)]
    expect = None
    for f in funcs:
        result = []
        f(l)
        if expect is None:
            expect = result
        else:
            assert result == expect

# Speed
def foo(a, b, c):
    pass
l = list(range(10**5))
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(l), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)

Attempt This Online!

You can use the windowed or sliding_window function from more_itertools which can handle this kind of sliding window iteration over a sequence.
from more_itertools import windowed
# You can use sliding_window as an alternative from more_itertools import sliding_window 


def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for values in windowed(l, 3):
    foo(*values)

If you don't want to use an external library, you can still make your code a bit more  Pythonic using generator expressions and the zip function:
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for values in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):
    foo(*values)


Your last implementation using zip is the fastest.

Where do you think you have generator expressions?

@nocomment I'm referring to the the input to zip

I am not seeing any generator expressions with regards to input to zip, which are slices, and zip itself returns an iterator.

I've tested (timeit) solutions by Parman and results are similar to my code. I find zip solution the most elegant (although I'd agree that it has nothing to do with generators)

@nocomment @Booboo @Szym Correct me if I'm wrong, a generator expression in python is defined: "It is similar to a list comprehension, but instead of creating a list, it creates a generator object that can be iterated over to produce the values in the generator". (l, l[1:], l[2:])  creates 3 iterators that align with the above definition.

Those are neither generator expressions nor iterators. And they don't align with that definition at all.

I retract my statement that Parman zip solution is similar in speed as original (mine). It is as in @nocomment answer 2x faster. My mistake was to use print(timeit.timeit('original', globals=globals(), number=1)) statement with global list L instead of using lambdas. Although I still don't get why using string statement in timeit drastically changes  results.

@Szym Not sure how you measured exactly. If you show your script, probably I can see the reason.

@nocomment I added it temporarily to my question. I'm pretty sure there's something I don't understand about timeit function.

@Szym It reports times like 0.002 seconds. How fast is your computer that you're not shocked you can do 999998 Python loop iterations 100000 times in such a short time? :-) You're not calling/executing the functions. Should use timeit('original()', ...) or timeit(original, ...).

for Pythonic and possibly more efficient :
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Iterate over indices directly
for i in range(len(l) - 2):
    foo(l[i], l[i + 1], l[i + 2])


Recommendation: Perhaps provide some benchmark tests to verify the validity of the ‘possibly more efficient’ statement.  On its own, without backing evidence it’s a useless assertion.
